# Django DecimalField rejecting all values with 2 and more decimal places

Tags: python, django, django-models, decimal

I have a model:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
```

with a test:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestAccount:
    def test_it_accepts_valid_data(self):
        data = {"profile_id": create_profile().id, "balance": 10.55}

        account = Account(**data)
        account.full_clean()
        account.save()
```

Which fails with the exception:

```
FAILED wallets/tests/test_model.py::TestAccount::test_models - django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'balance': ['Ensure that there are no more than 2 decimal places.']}
```

Reducing the test balance to a one decimal place figure e.g 10.5 passes the test. The interesting part is increasing the `decimal_places` argument to a higher figure e.g 5, still raises the exception on any figure with more than one decimal place

Am I missing something or is this a Django bug? I'm on python3.9 and Django 4.0.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A float value of 10.55 is actually stored as 10.55000019073486328125, you might have to explicitly state that the 10.55 is a decimal value like Decimal('10.55') instead of allowing it to remain a float

Comment: Thanks. I had tried using an explicit Decimal but I was passing in a float instead of a string. I'll need to do some refresher on Decimal type.